# Fixed Point for functions of several variables

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Can someone solve, or help me solve this problem in Numerical Analysis in chapter Fixed Point for functions of several variables.
Chapter 10, exercise set 10.1 problem 4.
The problem is explained in the picture.
This is the book , page 637 is the problem,
page 630 is Fixed Point for functions of several variables chapter.
https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/numerical_analysis_9th.pdf

[The problem in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cjrz.png)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDg9F.png)

[Formulas in x_i = g_i(x) form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BJBP.png)

[Iterations for point (3,11)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh4qA.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry i was busy, with some other work. I will check it tomorrow and i will send you what i archived. Thank you for trying to help me..

Comment: @Moo i edited the question for my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nonlinear system
$$−x(x + 1) + 2y = 18, (x − 1)^2 + (x − 6)^2 = 25$$
has two solutions.

a. Approximate the solutions graphically.
b. Use the approximations from part (a) as initial approximations for an appropriate function iteration, and determine the solutions to within $10^{−5}$ in the $l_\infty$ norm.

A [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%E2%88%92x%28x+%2B+1%29+%2B+2y+%3D+18%2C+%28x+%E2%88%92+1%29%5E2+%2B+%28y+%E2%88%92+6%29%5E2+%3D+25%7D) contour plot shows the two intersection points of $(-2, 10)$ and $(1.54695, 10.97)$.

[image]

After trial and error (there can be more than a single set of functions dervied), lets choose the first function as

$$\begin{align} g_1(x, y) &= \dfrac{2 y-18}{x+1} \\ g_2(x, y) &= \sqrt{25-(x-1)^2}+6 \end{align}$$

Starting at $x_0, y_0) = (3, 11)$, we have the iterates

$$\{\{3.00000000000000,11.0000000000000\},\{1.00000000000000,10.58257569495584\},\{1.58257569495584,11.00000000000000000000000000000\},\{1.54884133998961,10.965944578793316\},\{1.54261824614107,10.969786029953242\},\{1.54941547591172,10.970469337895043\},\{1.54582048827515,10.969722591335325\},\{1.54741671724848,10.970118710310557\},\{1.546758091811950,10.969943152358677\},\{1.547020236191428,10.9700156527960911\},\{1.546917943409719,10.9699868069439655\},\{1.546957421256077,10.9699980647055068\}$$

For the second point (this one has a very narrow area of convergence)

$$\begin{align} g_1(x, y) &= -\sqrt{2 y-17.75}-\dfrac{1}{2} \\ g_2(x, y) &= \sqrt{25-(x-1)^2}+6 \end{align}$$

Starting at $x_0, y_0) = (-3, 12)$, we have the iterates

$$\{\{-3.00000000000000,12.0000000000000\},\{-3.,9.00000000000000\},\{-1.,9.\},\{-1.,10.5826\},\{-2.34801,10.5826\},\{-2.34801,9.7136\},\{-1.79507,9.7136\},\{-1.79507,10.1458\},\{-2.09424,10.1458\},\{-2.09424,9.92756\},\{-1.9509,9.92756\},\{-1.9509,10.0364\},\{-2.02405,10.0364\},\{-2.02405,9.98185\},\{-1.98785,9.98185\},\{-1.98785,10.0091\},\{-2.00604,10.0091\},\{-2.00604,9.99546\},\{-1.99697,9.99546\},\{-1.99697,10.0023\},\{-2.00151,10.0023\},\{-2.00151,9.99887\},\{-1.99924,9.99887\},\{-1.99924,10.0006\},\{-2.00038,10.0006\},\{-2.00038,9.99972\},\{-1.99981,9.99972\},\{-1.99981,10.0001\},\{-2.00009,10.0001\},\{-2.00009,9.99993\},\{-1.99995,9.99993\},\{-1.99995,10.\},\{-2.00002,10.\},\{-2.00002,9.99998\},\{-1.99999,9.99998\},\{-1.99999,10.\},\{-2.00001,10.\},\{-2.00001,10.\},\{-2.,10.\}$$

You can verify the $l_\infty$ norm statement.

Comment: Thank i will check it out. Thank you alot